# How can I fix '/asana failed with the error "user_not_visible"' on Slack?

Tags: slack, asana

I asked someone with admin privileges to install the Asana Slack [app](https://asana.com/apps/slack).

They did and it is working for them but when I try to to call `/asana` I get this error:

```
/asana failed with the error "user_not_visible"
```

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: What Slack app are you using, web, desktop (installable) or mobile (installable) ?

Comment: I'm using desktop mac app

Comment: Then the question is off-topic here unless you are able to reproduce the problem using the Slacks' web app.

Comment: Just reproduced in Slack web app and mobile app

Answer (score 1):

This has probably something to do with `user_not_visible` Slack API error. [`user.info`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info) API call returns this error when `The requested user is not visible to the calling user`. In this case, it could be related to the token that Asana bot is using.